# Determining current of inductor

Tags: circuit-analysis

Given the following circuit:

[image]

For \$ t  \leq 0 \$ we have this circuit: will \$i_L = 0A \$? If not then how can i calculate \$i_L(t)\$

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an ideal circuit where both the switch and the inductor have 0 resistance, you actually have an undefined situation.

Firstly, we need to either know or make an assumption about how long the switch has been closed for. If we can assume the switch has been closed for a very long time, the first step is to ignore the capacitor, as at DC the capacitor is an open circuit.

Next, we consider the three other paths, the switch, inductor, and resistor, which at DC have resistances of 0Ω, 0Ω, and 400Ω respectively. We can ignore the resistor, as it's much bigger than the 0Ω paths, but we can't actually say how the current would be split.

Consider a current divider between two parallel resistors and a current source. The current in one is

I<sub>R1</sub> = I<sub>Total</sub> * R1 / (R1 + R2)
In this case, where both resistances are 0, we end up trying to divide by 0, and the result is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's model the switch a s a resitor with value \$\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{switch}\$. The current trough the coil can be found using Laplace transform and th current divider formula:

$$\text{I}_\text{L}\left(t\right)=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\text{i}_\text{source}}{\text{s}}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{switch}}+\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}}+\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{R}}}}{\displaystyle\text{sL}+\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{switch}}+\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}}+\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{R}}}}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\tag1$$

Which gives, when simplified:

$$\text{I}_\text{L}\left(t\right)=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\text{i}_\text{source}}{\text{s}}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle1+\text{sL}\left(\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{switch}}+\text{sC}+\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{R}}\right)}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\tag2$$

Now, you can analyze both cases with \$\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{switch}\to0\$ and \$\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{switch}\to\infty\$.